# how to make PlayerController Script use Touch Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make my PlayerController Script get touch input to make the player move in unity5? I tried changing the `Input.GetKeyDown` to `GetMouseDown` and `GetTouch`, but nothing happens when ever I click on the buttons, please help...thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

private static PlayerController instance;

public static PlayerController Instance 
{
    get 
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}

private Animator myAnimator;

[SerializeField]
private Transform bulletPosition;

[SerializeField]
private float movementSpeed;

private bool facingRight;

[SerializeField]
private Transform[] groundPoints;

[SerializeField]
private float groundRadius;

[SerializeField]
private LayerMask whatIsGround;

[SerializeField]
public bool airControl;

[SerializeField]
private float jumpForce;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject bulletPrefab;

public Rigidbody2D MyRigidbody{ get; set;}

public bool Attack{ get; set;}

public bool Jump{ get; set;}

public bool OnGround{ get; set;}

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    facingRight = true;
    MyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    HandleInput();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Debug.Log(horizontal);

    OnGround = IsGrounded();

    HandleMovement(horizontal);

    Flip(horizontal);

    HandleLayers();
}

private void HandleMovement(float horizontal)
{
    if (MyRigidbody.velocity.y < 0) 
    {
        myAnimator.SetBool("land", true);
    }
    if (!Attack && (OnGround || airControl)) 
    {
        MyRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * movementSpeed, MyRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }
    if (Jump && MyRigidbody.velocity.y == 0) 
    {
        MyRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }

    myAnimator.SetFloat ("speed", Mathf.Abs (horizontal));
}

private void HandleInput()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        myAnimator.SetTrigger("jump");
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        myAnimator.SetTrigger("attack");
    }
}

private void Flip(float horizontal)
{
    if(horizontal > 0 && !facingRight || horizontal < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;

        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

        theScale.x *= -1;

        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}

private bool IsGrounded()
{
    if(MyRigidbody.velocity.y <= 0)
    {
        foreach(Transform point in groundPoints)
        {
            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

            for(int i = 0; i <colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if(colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void HandleLayers()
{
    if(!OnGround)
    {
        myAnimator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        myAnimator.SetLayerWeight(1, 0);
    }
}

public void ShootBullet(int value)
{
    if(!OnGround && value == 1 || OnGround && value == 0)
    {
        if (facingRight) 
        {
            GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletPosition.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)));
            tmp.GetComponent<Bullet>().Initialize(Vector2.right);
        } 
        else 
        {
            GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletPosition.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 180)));
            tmp.GetComponent<Bullet>().Initialize(Vector2.left);
        }
    }
}
}
```